# Access static class variable of parent class in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, static-variables

I have someting like this

```
class A:
  __a = 0
  def __init__(self):
    A.__a = A.__a + 1
  def a(self):
    return A.__a

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    # how can I access / modify A.__a here?
    A.__a = A.__a + 1 # does not work
  def a(self):
    return A.__a
```

Can I access the `__a` class variable in `B`? It's possible writing `a` instead of `__a`, is this the only way? (I guess the answer might be rather short: yes :)

Comment: What is your reason for using the double underscore attribute name? Is one underscore not sufficient - used to indicate a 'private' attribute?

Comment: Well, that's something for a Python expert to answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, `__a` isn't a *static* variable, it's a class variable. And because of the double leading underscore, it's a [name mangled](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) variable. That is, to make it pseudo-private, it's been automagically renamed to `_<classname>__<variablename>` instead of `__<variablename>`. It can still be accessed by instances of *that class only* as `__<variablename>`, subclasses don't get this special treatment.

I would recommend that you not use the double leading underscore, just a single underscore to (a) mark that it is private, and (b) to avoid the name mangling.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to it as `A._A__a`. In Python, symbols with a `__` prefix occurring inside a class definition are prefixed with `_<class-name>` to make them somewhat ["private"](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers). Thus the reference `A.__a` that appears in the definition of `B` is, counterintuitively, a reference to `A._B__a`:

```
>>> class Foo(object): _Bar__a = 42
... 
>>> class Bar(object): a = Foo.__a
... 
>>> Bar.a
42
```

Answer (score 1):

There are Python decorators `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`, which you can use to declare a method static or class-related. This should help accessing your class data element:

```
class MyClass:
     __a = 0

     @staticmethod
     def getA():
         return MyClass.__a

class MyOtherClass:

     def DoSomething(self):
         print MyClass.getA() + 1
```

Example inspired by this source:
http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/python_101/python_101.html

Comment: Should be  def getA(): return A.__a

Comment: Oops, true. Will correct. Also note that in my example class name is MyClass. ;)

Comment: Oops, I guess I like piling mistakes on top of mistakes...  :)